# Splitting nested arrays as separate entities

Tags: json, jq

I have some JSON data which contains attributes and some array elements. I would like to push a given set of fields into the array elements and then separate the arrays as separate entities.

Source data looks like this

```
[
  {
    "phones": [
      {
        "phone": "555-555-1234",
        "type": "home"
      },
      {
        "phone": "555-555-5678",
        "type": "mobile"
      }
    ],
    "email": [
      {
        "email": "a@b.com",
        "type": "work"
      },
      {
        "email": "x@c.com",
        "type": "home"
      }
    ],
    "name": "john doe",
    "year": "2012",
    "city": "cupertino",
    "zip": "555004"
  },
  {
    "phones": [
      {
        "phone": "555-666-1234",
        "type": "home"
      },
      {
        "phone": "555-666-5678",
        "type": "mobile"
      }
    ],
    "email": [
      {
        "email": "a@b.com",
        "type": "work"
      },
      {
        "email": "x@c.com",
        "type": "home"
      }
    ],
    "name": "jane doe",
    "year": "2000",
    "city": "los angeles",
    "zip": "555004"
  }
]
```

I expect a result like this

```
{
  "person": [
    {
      "name": "john doe",
      "year": "2012",
      "city": "cupertino",
      "zip": "555004"
    },
    {
      "name": "jane doe",
      "year": "2000",
      "city": "los angeles",
      "zip": "555004"
    }
  ],
  "phones": [
    {
      "name": "john doe",
      "year": "2012",
      "phone": "555-555-1234",
      "type": "home"
    },
    {
      "name": "john doe",
      "year": "2012",
      "phone": "555-555-5678",
      "type": "mobile"
    },
    {
      "name": "jane doe",
      "year": "2000",
      "phone": "555-666-1234",
      "type": "home"
    },
    {
      "name": "jane doe",
      "year": "2000",
      "phone": "555-666-5678",
      "type": "mobile"
    }
  ],
  "email": [
    {
      "name": "john doe",
      "year": "2012",
      "email": "a@b.com",
      "type": "work"
    },
    {
      "name": "john doe",
      "year": "2012",
      "email": "x@c.com",
      "type": "home"
    },
    {
      "name": "jane doe",
      "year": "2000",
      "email": "a@b.com",
      "type": "work"
    },
    {
      "name": "jane doe",
      "year": "2000",
      "email": "x@c.com",
      "type": "home"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have been able to get the desired result, but I can't make it work in a generic way.

[experiment on jqterm](https://jqterm.com/06f73b6a1ff837586e68085f7542b022?query=def%20split_child%28field%3B%20ids%29%3A%0A%20%20map%28%0A%20%20%20%20%28getpath%28%5Bfield%5D%29%7Carrays%5B%5D%20%2F%2F%20null%29%20as%20%24d%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20with_entries%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20.%20as%20%24data%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20select%28ids%7Ccontains%28%5B%24data.key%5D%29%29%0A%20%20%29%20%2B%20%24d%20%29%3B%0A%0A%0A%5B%22phones%22%2C%20%22email%22%5D%20as%20%24children%20%0A%7C%20%5B%22name%22%2C%20%22year%22%5D%20as%20%24ids%0A%7C%7Bperson%3A%20map%28with_entries%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20.%20as%20%24data%20%7C%20select%28%24children%7Ccontains%28%5B%24data.key%5D%29%7Cnot%29%0A%20%20%29%29%7D%0A%20%2B%20%7B%22phones%22%3A%20split_child%28%24children%5B0%5D%3B%24ids%29%7D%0A%20%2B%20%7B%22email%22%3A%20split_child%28%24children%5B1%5D%3B%24ids%29%7D%0A%20%20&raw=true)

The code below achieves the job, but I would like to pass the array of columns to be injected into the child arrays, the name of the primary result and an array containing the array field names.

```
["phones", "email"] as $children 
| ["name", "year"] as $ids
|{person: map(with_entries(
     . as $data | select($children|contains([$data.key])|not)
  ))}
 + {"phones": split_child($children[0];$ids)}
 + {"email": split_child($children[1];$ids)}
```

Comment: Modified the example to use phones and emails instead. I would like to use a function split_data(parent, ids, arr_cols) where parent = "person", ids = ["name","year"] and arr_cols = ["phones", "email"]

Comment: Thank you! I dunno who down-voted this, this is a nicely asked question, actually a perfect example of a good question. It was also before you edited it. This is unacceptable behaviour imo. I hope you will still have a good feeling about this site and continue to ask questions.

Comment: Thanks @hek2mgl. I do and there are really great and helpful people on the site. :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a lot more easier to achieve this using multiple `reduce`s, like:

```
def split_data($parent; $ids; $arr_cols):
    ($arr_cols | map([.])) as $p
    | reduce .[] as $in ({}; .[$parent] += [$in | delpaths($p)]
        | (reduce $ids[] as $k ({}; . + {($k): $in[$k]}) as $s
        | reduce $arr_cols[] as $k (.; .[$k] += [$in[$k][] + $s])
    );

split_data("person"; ["name", "year"]; ["phones", "email"])
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for this. I find the reduce a little difficult to understand.

Comment: @Jerry welcome. it's like a `for ... in ...` loop. its syntax is `reduce s as $var (init; update)`, it simply applies `update` to `init` for each product of `s`, saves the result into `init` back, and produces the final state of `init` at the end. mess around with it on your terminal and you will understand much better

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Makes sense now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward solution to the generic problem (it uses `reduce` only once, in a helper function).  To understand it, it might be helpful to see it as an abstraction of this concrete solution:

```
  { person: [.[] | {name, year, city, zip} ]}
+ { phones: [.[] | ({name, year} + .phones[]) ]}
+ { email:  [.[] | ({name, year} + .email[]) ]}
```

### Helper function

Let's first define a helper function for constructing an object by selecting a set of keys:

```
def pick($ary):
  . as $in
  | reduce $ary[] as $k ({};
      . + {($k): $in[$k]});
```

### split_data

Here finally is the function that takes as arguments the $parent, $ids, and columns of interest. The main complication is ensuring that the supplemental keys ("city" and "zip") are dealt with in the proper order.

```
def split_data($parent; $ids; $arr_cols):
  (.[0]|keys_unsorted - $arr_cols - $ids) as $extra
  | { ($parent): [.[] | pick($ids + $extra)] }
  + ([$arr_cols[] as $k
     | {($k): [.[] | pick($ids) + .[$k][]] }] | add) ;
```

The invocation:

```
split_data("person"; ["name", "year"]; ["phones", "email"])
```

produces the desired result.